# How do I installing GNOME Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I Just wanted to test the GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.10, but I'm getting the following error.

```
 gnome-shell : Depends: libcogl2 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install the libcog12 as well, but some packages will be removed, so I canceled because I don't want to crash my Ubuntu again:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by updates.

```
decent@decent:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.1.92

decent@decent:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
[sudo] password for decent: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

decent@decent:~$ uname -a
Linux decent 3.0.0-11-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 23:38:01 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

decent@decent:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu oneiric (development branch)
Release:    11.10
Codename:   oneiric
decent@decent:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

discussed here as a known issue. wait a few days
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1848618

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.